# log4j2 and syslog, using RFC5424 format does not show varargs part of log message

Tags: java, log4j2, syslog

I have this syslog appender configured:

```
    <Syslog name="syslog" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="514"
            protocol="UDP" appName="" includeMDC="true"
            facility="LOCAL0" enterpriseNumber="" newLine="true"
            messageId="" id="">
        <LoggerFields>
            <KeyValuePair key="c" value="%c{1}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="l" value="%p" />
            <KeyValuePair key="t" value="%t" />
        </LoggerFields>
    </Syslog>
```

The log messages in local0 do not get the varargs part of the log4j2 output. For example, this log statement in the code:

```
log.info("commit(). Query {}", query.getQuery());
```

will result in this output in local0.log (not the curly braces at the end):

```
Mar  3 20:09:22 127.0.0.1 1 2015-03-03T20:09:22.431Z app-03-prod.lax.projone.net  -  [mdc@18060 c="c.c.p.p.TransactionHelper" l="INFO" t="qtp812765588-375 - /id/1.0/credential?appKey=867ac7681942fb3ee5453b95378f155e"] commit(). Query {}
```

But in the application log file, I do get the varargs part of the statement:

```
2015-03-03 20:04:25,374 INFO c.c.p.p.TransactionHelper [qtp380256045-442 - /id/1.0/session/start?appKey=940d52aac10af731c83176e65a763f87] commit(). Query INSERT INTO oid_identity (oid, app_id, app_uid, platform_id, platform_uid, creation_time) VALUES ( UNHEX( ? ), ? , ?, ? , ? , ? ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE creation_time=creation_time
```

I must be missing something in the log4j2.xml config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pattern layout, `%t` stands for the thread name, and you would use `%m` to get the message.

If that does not answer your question, can you clarify your *expected* result? (You explained the steps to reproduce and the actual result, but it would be helpful if you can make explicit what output you expect/want to achieve.)

Comment: that worked, thanks. I now get the full message with curly braces replaced with text but also still with curly braces at the end of the message. Any idea if that can be removed? This is how it looks now `Mar  3 23:06:33 127.0.0.1 1 2015-03-03T23:06:33.980Z app-03-prod.lax.projone.net  -  [mdc@18060 c="c.c.o.m.OIDHelper" l="ERROR" m="getTree(): Invalid OID Tree. OID F636C2FC94100000000B6C94969340B5" t="qtp812765588-310 - /id/1.0/auth/151325310530324/accesstoken?sessionId=7209236797825832277&appKey=867ac7681942fb3ee5453b95378f155e"] getTree(): Invalid OID Tree. OID {}`

Comment: Looks like the logger fields are surrounded by square brackets `[key="value" key="value"]`, followed by the log message *pattern* only (without parameters). This may be a bug in log4j2, in which case you should raise a Jira. (Sorry, I am not familiar enough with the SysLogAppender to know how it is supposed to behave.)